# Python code with SPARQL not working

Tags: python-2.7, sparql, dbpedia, wikidata, sparqlwrapper

I'm writing a python code to match the list of actors between DBPEDIA and WIKIDATA. First i'm retrieving the list of actors with some additional information such as birth date, birth place from Dbpedia using SPARQL and using the same list of actors which are retrieved from Dbpedia, i'm trying to retrieve some additional information such as awards received. My python code is throwing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a hunch that the dbpedia portion of the query is timing out within wikidata.  Skipping the federated binding and adding a limit, the query goes to completion, but takes several seconds.  Un-comment the triple about the awards, and it times out.

Since there are problems with the SPARQL, I'm going to ignore the Python processing for now.

Independent of that, I found two glitches:

```
# missing prefixes
PREFIX  wdt:  <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

PREFIX  dbp:  <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT  *
WHERE {
SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
  ?c  rdf:type    <http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/Actor> ;
        rdfs:label  ?Actor
    FILTER ( lang(?Actor) = "en" )
    ?c  dbo:deathDate   ?Death_date ;
        dbo:birthPlace  ?b
# date filterning not working... add cast
    FILTER ( xsd:date(?Death_date) >= "1990 - 01 - 01"^^xsd:date )
    ?b  rdfs:label  ?birth_Place
    FILTER ( lang(?birth_Place) = "en" )
    ?Starring  rdf:type       dbo:Film ;
              dbo:starring    ?c .
    ?c        dbo:deathCause  ?d .
    ?d        dbp:name        ?Cause_Of_Death .
    ?c        owl:sameAs      ?wikidata_actor
    FILTER strstarts(str(?wikidata_actor), "http://www.wikidata.org")
  }
# ?wikidata_actor wdt:P166 ?award_received.
}
LIMIT  9
```

Every SPARQL endpoint has its own unique personality.  So in my opinion, federated queries (which use the `service` keyword and hit two or more endpoints) can be especially tricky.  In case you're new to federation, here's an unrelated query that works.

There is some entity that tweets under the name 'darwilliamstour'.  What is the name of that entity?

```
select *
where
{
?twitterer wdt:P2002 'darwilliamstour' .
service <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>
{
?twitterer rdfs:label ?name
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I made the changes and now my SPARQL query is working fine.

Comment: My pleasure.  Please consider marking the question answered.